# Adobe PDF networking error

Tags: networking, windows-server-2012, adobe-reader

I have several users on a 2012 RDS server that access a PDF from a Server 2012 windows file server. This PDF has many fillable fields like Name: with an empty text box next to it.

Sometimes when the users open this PDF everything is missing except the fillable text fields. If they try to save the file they get the following error:

the document could not be saved. an unexpected network error occurred

Obviously, this sounds like a networking error, but 2 things.

1) The terminal server and the file server on both VMs on the same ESXi host, using the same SAN. Seems unlikely to be a networking error. No other networking errors on any server.

2) This doesn't happen to every user, it seems to be only affecting 3 of about 40 right now, and it doesn't happen all the time.

Any thoughts? I have checked to see if there were any hidden lock files, but that wasn't it. Google-fu turned up nothing. When a user accesses a file from a file share, where do the lock files get created? I see no lock files in the shared folder, are they in the user profile somewhere?

Only other avenue I've considered: Is this a problem with how Server 2012 handles simultaneous users accessing the same file? The file is pushed out with GPP.

Aside from just nuking the affected users profiles I'm not sure what else to try. Adobe is up-to-date.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Well, because you already said it I won't post it as my answer, but I would nuke the profiles and see if the problem comes back.  Because it is an RDS server the place I would look for possible profile corruption is in the registry under HKLM > Software > Microsoft > Windows NT > Current Version > Profile List.  Under there you'll see a bunch of SIDs/GUIDs for the profiles on the computer that won't make sense until you click on them and look at who they actually are... if you see any with .BAK extensions they are corrupted and should/can be removed for better results.

Comment: Also, make sure the profile is fully removed after deleting these from the registry under Right-click Computer > Properties > Advanced System Settings > User Profiles.

Comment: (Sorry, cant "comment" without enough rep, I don't use serverfault) Did you ever sort this out? (I saw your post on abode forums too) I am having this exact problem across multiple machines, different PDFs (similar template). I have a suspicion... are the files held on a 2012 server with DeDupe enabled? (InDesign does something very similar on a Mac. It can't handle the dedupe flags.) I have my users save the PDFs to the desktop and then edit them from there, then copy back to shared storage. Attached is a screenshot of the error.(Turns out i cant post images...) Note that the document in the